# How come console app doesn't end?

Tags: visual-c++

My first time working with Visual C++ (new to the language, too) - experienced C# ...so I have my first console app that I started in Visual Studio.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i;

    cin >> i;

    return 0;
}
```

How come the console window - thus the application - doesn't close when I press enter? No other input - just enter ...

More importantly, how can I make the app exit (don't want to use `exit()`) properly if I just hit enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::cin awaits one non-empty string from you and then tries to convert this string to integer.

When you press Enter std::cin only gets an empty string and continues to wait for some valid input. This is by design. std::cin is not meant for emulating other interaction.

To terminate the app on keypress, you have to use OS-specific facilities to read keyboard presses.

This is the kbhit() function from "conio.h" on DOS/console Windows and the termio functions on POSIX systems.

From your source I can conclude that you use the MSVC++ compiler, so try replacing

```
std::cin >> i
```

by

```
while(!kbhit()) {}
```

Do not forget to add the

```
#include <conio.h>
```

and remember this is a Windows-specific solution.

Comment: +1 for the extra explanation. I also found that I could write `cin.get(c);` and I could get the desired result. I'll look up `<conio.h>` too ...thanks!

Comment: Yes, cin.get(c) reads any char (including the CR/LF which is generated on Enter press) so this also works. Good point.